# Polr function error: "response must be a factor"

Tags: r

I'm using the `polr` function to run an ordered logistic regression. `Reglog` is my data frame and `Reglog$wtp` is the response variable. Here is a list of all the variables in my model.

1. wtp <- Reglog$WTP
2. perception<- Reglog$Persepsi
3. income <- Reglog$pendapatan
4. age <- Reglog$usia
5. education <- Reglog$usia
6. experience <- Reglog$pengalaman
7. home <- Reglog$rumah

At the first, `wtp` was `chr`, so I converted it into an `ordered factor`.

```
Reglog$WTP <- as.ordered(Reglog$WTP) 

str(Reglog) 
tibble [30 x 7] (S3:
tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)  
$ WTP : Ord.factor w/ 3 levels "1"<"2"<"3": 1 1 3 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 ...
```

The result shows that `wtp` is an ordered factor,  but when I use `polr` to run the regression, it says that `wtp` is not a factor.

```
> model <- polr(wtp~persepsi+pendapatan+usia+pendidikan+pengalaman+pendapatanrt, data = Reglog, Hess = TRUE)
Error in polr(wtp ~ persepsi + pendapatan + usia + pendidikan + pengalaman +  : 
  response must be a factor
```

How do I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you use all caps in one reference to WTP and non-caps in another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to use `method = "logistic"`.

```
polr(wtp ~ persepsi + pendapatan + usia + pendidikan + pengalaman + pendapatanrt, data = Reglog, Hess = TRUE, method = "logistic")
```

Then wrap the dependent variable in `as.factor()`:

```
polr(as.factor(wtp) ~ persepsi + pendapatan + usia + pendidikan + pengalaman + pendapatanrt, data = Reglog, Hess = TRUE, method = "logistic")
```

Comment: Okay. But I got another error: unexpected string constant in polr. It was intended to `wtp`, so I converted it to ordered factor, but that error still remains. How do I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: I had the same error and the 'polr(as.factor()' solution worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the response variable as factor like this

```
Reglog<- within(Reglog, {  
  wtp  <- factor(wtp , labels=c('l1','l2','l3'))
})
```